# CSV generated with filecontents results in empty table rows when parsed with csvsimple

Tags: csvsimple, filecontents

I just stumbled over an unexpected (or maybe actually not so unexpected) behaviour of `csvsimple` when feeding `\csvreader` with CSV data generated by `filecontents`.

It seems that starting with TeX Live 2021 or so, `csvsimple` has problems with parsing the CSV file generated by `filecontents`, probably because the file starts with four lines that start with a percent sign. The output is a tabular that has four empty rows.

I could reproduce this using Overleaf with TeX Live 2022 and 2021 as well as with my local MiKTeX 22.3 installation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents}{mydata.csv}
1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l} \hline
\textbf{Column 1} \\ \hline
\csvreader[
    no head,
    late after line = \\ \hline
]{mydata.csv}{}{%
    \csvcoli 
} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to confirm that I did not overlook something, I am posting this here. What would be the best way to tackle this issue? Is there a way not prevent these four lines from being inserted into the generated CSV file?

Was the addition of the commented lines in the generated file only introduced at some point in time (which would explain why the above code works nicely with older TeX installations)?

Comment: The most simple solution would be not to print the offending lines to begin with: `\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{mydata.csv}`

Comment: This is actually exactly the option I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments that `filecontents` produces can be suppressed by either using the starred version:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.csv}
1
\end{filecontents*}
```

or by adding the option `noheader`:

```
\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{mydata.csv}
1
\end{filecontents}
```

For more details, see http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews30.pdf